# SwiftUI 2.0 Text alignment justify

Tags: swiftui

Does SwiftUI 2.0 Text support "justify" multiline text alignment.

And if not, is there a way, without using UIKit, to achieve 'justified' alignment?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we still don't have alignment type as justified in SwiftUI. You have to use UIKIT with `UIViewRepresentable`